# VB.Net Dynamically Referencing a Variable or Control

Tags: vb.net

It would take too long to try an explain the actual application I am building.

Lets just say, I have 3 textboxes on my form. I want to set each one of them to a value of the numerical index. This is how I would normally do it.

```
txt1.Text = "1"
txt2.Text = "2"
txt3.Text = "3"
```

Now, if I had 100 of these textboxes, I would want to do something more like this.

```
For i as Integer = 1 to 3
    txt[i].Text = i
Next
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `Me.Controls("TextBox" & i.ToString()) = i.ToString()` or put the names in a List and use that especially if they are scattered across containers (if I understand correctly)

Comment: I would suggest putting the controls in a collection if you can.  Assuming that they are in the appropriate z-order, all have the same parent and you want all controls of that type on that parent, you can use `Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().ToArray()`.

Comment: Ok. Perfect. You missed the ".Text" for the Property to set, but yes. That worked. Thank you!

Comment: One more question. What if these were variables, instead of Controls?

Comment: for vars, what you are doing is emulating an array so just use an array or List... `myVars(n)` is the nTh item

Comment: What I would normally do is use the `Tag` Property as an index that way you can iterate through your collection and know which item you are putting the data in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it: first, create a list or an array (depending on whether the number of textboxes is fixed or not) and add you textboxes to it:

```
Dim txtList as new list(of textbox)
txtList.items.add(txtBox1...
```

This can be done automatically using jmcilhinney's method (with the same caveats):

```
Dim txtList = New List(Of TextBox)(Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().ToArray())
```

Then you can reference it as such:

```
txtList(i).text
```

I hope that's what you were asking and that it helps :)

Comment: @jmcilhinney 's method creates that for you without typing them  out in code.  for a list, `txtList = New List(Of TextBox)(Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().ToArray())`  if you add or remove one, the code is still correct

Comment: Ahh cool, I didn't know you could do that, I'll edit appropriately

Comment: This is PERFECT! There are many other textboxes on my form, that don't apply to these, so I can't add them automatically, but all the controls are fixed, so I can hard code them into the list. thank you guys.... 280 lines of code, across 5 subroutines, converted to 18 lines.

Comment: @BrianLefler you could get all TBs on the form and filter the result using linq if the special ones had a different pattern to the name.  Hard to be specific without knowing more.  Click the checkbox if this is in fact, Perfect or nearly so.